# Pyspark does not display the hive database

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive

I try to connect to hive database via pyspark, but can't see my database (only default)

```
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.4.5
      /_/

Using Python version 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019 20:35:49)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>> spark.sql('show databases')
DataFrame[databaseName: string]
>>> spark.sql('show databases').show()
+------------+
|databaseName|
+------------+
|     default|
+------------+
```

But if i do this command using hive I get the following:

```
hive> show databases;
OK
signals
default
test
Time taken: 0.973 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
hive>
```

What I should do to connect to me hive instance?

Comment: what is the pyspark shell command you are using

Comment: pyspark (but I have the same results using spark-shell)

Comment: If Spark can't find your Hive metastore, it starts an embedded one which is empty. As below answer says, add `hive-site.xml` to your classpath. Or try starting a session with `pyspark --conf  hive.metastore.uris=thrift://hostname:port ...`.

Comment: Warning: Ignoring non-Spark config property: hive.metastore.uris

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether you have configured spark to use hive metastore.

Go to `SPARK_HOME/conf/hive-site.xml`.
And check the following property, if it's not there add that.

```xml
<configuration>
  <property>
  <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
    <!-- hostname must point to the Hive metastore URI in your cluster -->
    <value>thrift://hostname:port</value>
    <description>URI for client to contact metastore server</description>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

**Note:** If you don’t know hostname and port of your metastore, go to `HIVE_HOME/conf/hive-site.xml`. You can find those property there

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer. I think that problem because I use spark 2.4.5 version with Hive 3.1.2 and Hadoop 3.1.3. What do you think about that?

Comment: I haven’t used hadoop3 with spark2. Don’t know about the consequences.